# Creating a structure with an expanded index sequence

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, index-sequence

I want to be able to use parameter pack expansion in the initializer list of constructors. Is the best way to achieve this, to endow my class with a parameter pack template argument? Here is an example of what I mean:
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e699c4cd035e0b1c

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, std::size_t...Is>
struct base_vec
{
    constexpr static std::size_t N = sizeof...(Is);
    T e[N];
    base_vec() : e{} {}
    explicit base_vec(const T& s) : e{((void)Is,s)...} {}
};


template<typename T, std::size_t...Is>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& lhs, const base_vec<T,Is...>& rhs)
{
    return (std::cout << ... << rhs.e[Is]);
}



template<typename T, std::size_t...Is>
constexpr auto getVecIs(std::index_sequence<Is...> seq)
{
    return base_vec<T, Is...>{};
}




template<typename T, std::size_t N>
using vec = decltype(getVecIs<T>(std::declval<std::make_index_sequence<N>>()));

int main()
{
    vec<int,3> v(2);
    std::cout << v << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Note the trivial expansion `e{((void)Is,s)...}`. Is this an ok practice, or am I missing some minus of this approach (except for the fact that now my structure will have a whole parameter pack, as opposed to a single `size_t N`)?

Comment: It entirely depends on what you want `vec` to represent, what you want its API to look like, and how you want it to be used. What you have done seems reasonable... assuming that you want something like `std::array`.

Comment: @lightxbulb You can always use `std::fill` in combination with `std::begin` and `std::end` on the member array in the constructor of the class.

Comment: @PetokLorand `std::fill` is not compile time.

Comment: And that assumes that `T` is default constructible.

Comment: @lightxbulb Your member array is not compile-time either, it's a normal array that will be allocated on the stack, and populated at run-time in your example too.

Comment: @PetokLorand If you add in some `constexpr` here and there, the operations are compile time - meaning that you will get a `e{s,s,...,s}` in code, whereas with a for loop this is not the case - produces also different assembly.

Comment: @lightxbulb Take a look at godbolt, and the generated code for the constructor https://godbolt.org/z/lI44bF. Note that the optimizations are disabled to not let the compiler optimize away the call, the compiler optimization would hide the fact that it's not required to be done at compile time.

Comment: @PetokLorand: Add missing `constexpr`, and OP code would be `constexpr` too [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xzgxTr), but [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) would be `constexpr` in C++20. so anyway, it was a wrong argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the expansion entirely inside the class:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct vec
{
public:
    T e[N];
    vec() : e{} {}
    explicit vec(const T& s) : vec{s, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}} {}
private:
    template <std::size_t ... Is>
    vec(const T& s, std::index_sequence<Is...>) : e{(Is, s)...} {}
};
```

Comment: I actually have written the exact same version previously! I wasn't sure which is better though. The version I have written here, allows to do this without making extra functions, and that number increases with every other function (for example for `operator<<`. The only thing I am not sure about is, if I have `vec<T,N,M>`, then I will need to expand the two parameter packs, but then C++ cannot differentiate those in the context: `base_vec<T,Ns...,Ms...>`.

Comment: @lightxbulb it can, if they are deduced. If you often need to iterate over your array at compile-time, you can provide a higher-order function to do that as well.

Comment: @lightxbulb: For `operator<<`, you might use regular for range. For generic case, you might still have the possibility to create a template member `for_each`, to avoid to duplicate each method.

Comment: @Quentin Could you elaborate, since I am getting an error: `error: parameter pack 'Is' must be at the end of the template parameter list`. I am not exactly sure how to combine two non-type parameter packs without ambiguity. Maybe with dummy templates?

Comment: One of the main points in OPs example seems to be to have the parameter pack readily available as used in `operator<<`. That makes this seem like a step backwards.

Comment: @super: Not sure what was the main point of OP, I provide solution without intermediate class. BTW, OP's code already works...

Comment: @lightxbulb hard to say without seeing your code, but [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YyF7SUd2suxJSysU) is what I mean. It does require some hoop-hopping.

Comment: @Quentin I see it after the examples presented, it seems like I hadn't provided the arguments required for deduction in my case, which was causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you're recreating a class inspired to `std::array` with an handy index sequence to operate.

Intriguing.

I propose a simplification (IMHO) that directly define `vec`, avoiding `base_vec`, using template specialization

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct vec;

template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t...Is>
struct vec<T, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 {
    T e[N] {} ;

    vec (const T& s) : e{((void)Is,s)...}
     { }
 };


template <typename T, std::size_t...Is>
std::ostream& operator<< (
   std::ostream& lhs,
   vec<T, sizeof...(Is), std::index_sequence<Is...>> const & rhs)
 { return (std::cout << ... << rhs.e[Is]); }

int main ()
 {
    vec<int, 3u> v(2);

    std::cout << v << "\n";
 }
```

You can add, in the body of the `vec` specialization, a `static_assert()`
as follows

```
static_assert( N == sizeof...(Is) );
```

to avoid "hijacked" uses as follows

```
vec<int, 5u, std::make_index_sequence<12u>>  bad_vec_1;
```

or, maybe better,

```
static_assert( std::is_same_v<std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                              std::make_index_sequence<N>> );
```

to avoid aslo

```
vec<int, 5u, std::index_sequence<1u, 3u, 5u, 2u, 4u>>  bad_vec_2;
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP asks

> Any ideas how to extend this to multiple index sequences - for multi-dimensional arrays for example?

It's simple.

As suggested by Jarod42, you can add another `N` and anther `std::index_sequence`.

I propose as follows for the 2 dim case.

I've also added a third index sequence for `N1*N2` (I suppose can be useful).

I leave the body of the specialization as exercise.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2,
          typename = std::make_index_sequence<N1>,
          typename = std::make_index_sequence<N2>,
          typename = std::make_index_sequence<N1*N2>>
struct vec2dim;

template <typename T, std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2,
          std::size_t ... Is, std::size_t ... Js, std::size_t ... Ks>
struct vec2dim<T, N1, N2, std::index_sequence<Is...>,
               std::index_sequence<Js...>, std::index_sequence<Ks...>>
 {
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                                 std::make_index_sequence<N1>> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<std::index_sequence<Js...>,
                                 std::make_index_sequence<N2>> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<std::index_sequence<Ks...>,
                                 std::make_index_sequence<N1*N2>> );
   // ...
 };
```

Comment: But `vec<int, 6u, std::index_sequence<4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42>>` would be partially usable

Comment: I was initially trying to make the version you have above, but didn't quite manage to get the code right. Any ideas how to extend this to multiple index sequences - for multi-dimensional arrays for example? How will the compiler differentiate between the two parameter packs? Would some dummy templates help? Or should I go for a nested approach?

Comment: @Jarod42 - answer improved to solve this type of problems (see second proposed `static_assert()`)

Comment: @lightxbulb: Similarly, you might do: `template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<M>, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct vec2;`.

Comment: @Jarod42 How would the `template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M, std::size_t...Ns, std::size_t...Ms>` part work out though? I get the following error if I try to use two parameter packs: `error: parameter pack 'Ns' must be at the end of the template parameter list` since it's obviously ambiguous. I can make a new question if this is deemed too unrelated to the current one.

Comment: @lightxbulb: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cfab5d939d62fe8)

Comment: @lightxbulb - answer improved for 2D case (but, I see now, is almost the same in the Jarod42 demo)